# SHA1 generation on .net4

Tags: c#, .net, hash, sha1

I reused some old code and come saw that I had been using this code to generate a SHA1 hash.

```
HashAlgorithm sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
return sha.ComputeHash((new UnicodeEncoding()).GetBytes(password.Trim()));
```

When I use the following code to generate a SHA1-hash I do not end up with the same hash as when I test with, for example, http://gtools.org/tool/sha1-hash-generator/

Which one is correct?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely a difference in encoding. You're using UTF-16. Try using UTF-8.

Just confirmed that this site uses UTF-8. But their code is broken for certain characters, such as `'`, because they put their input through sql escaping.

But hashing a password with plain SHA-1 is almost never the correct choice. In most cases, such as storing passwords used for login to your site you should use a proper password hashing functions, such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt with an appropriate salt.

PBKDF2 is implemented in .net in the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx)

Comment: Make that "an *unseeded single* application of SHA-1 is almost never..."

Comment: Thanks for the input! Is that also the case when only running it over SSL?

Comment: @nj. SSL is irrelevant in this context, since the passwords are stored hashed in the db, to protect against a stolen db. The password sent over the network should not be hashed, but protected with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Example of SHA-1 salting:

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(
    new HMACSHA1(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt))
    .ComputeHash(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)));
```

Comment: My understanding is that this function is designed as a MAC. Which in turn means that it is fast. You need to use an iteration scheme to slow it down, which is exactly what PBKDF2 does.